# Fix divs height HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here I'm another time with another newbie problem :S
I've tried about 2h how to set the Blue background the same height as the white background, but setting "height: 100% or height: 100vh" doesn't work.

https://jsbin.com/sideto/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I'll do like you said the next time, and thanks for answer me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove padding from this class

```
div.c1 { height: 100vh; background: #fff; margin-top: -30px; padding: 60px 30px; }
```

checkout this
https://jsbin.com/hekusezobi/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Try removing div.c1 padding :

```
div.c1 { height: 100vh; background: #fff; margin-top: -30px;  }
```

When you put a padding to a component, you basically say to the browser that you want some space around the content of your component. The [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/padding) may help you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to achieve, but as I understand it it's the padding on div.c1. Change CSS to:

div.c1 { height: 100vh; background: #fff; margin-top: -30px; padding: 0px 30px; }